# Get value with a dynamic and complex key in JSON - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Is there a way to access a JSON value with a composed string key ?

Let me explain, I have a following JSON Object :

```yaml
{
 "guy1":
 {
  "name":"Joe"
 }
}
```

Suppose we have an array `guysArray` containing multiple JSON Objects similar to the one above and a string variable

```js
let pathToName = "guy1.name"
```

---

I noticed it's impossible to do like that :

```js
guysArray[i].pathToName
```

The only correct way :

```js
guysArray[i].guy1.name

guysArray[i]["guy1"]["name"]
```

How could I do that programmatically without having to write the path element by element ?

Am I obligated to create a loop structure or there is a better saving structure for `pathToName` ?

Comment: Check out [Lodash.get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get)

Comment: I didn't know this library expose this function ! That's perfect, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```js
let yourData = `{
 "guy1":
 {
  "name":"Joe"
 }
}`

let stringToJson = JSON.parse(yourData)
let wantedValue = stringToJson['guy1'].name

console.log(wantedValue)
```

Comment: Your code `stringToJson['guy1'].name` is similar to `stringToJson['guy1']["name"]` or `stringToJson.guy1.name` and I'm not looking for that.

Comment: I need a way to do `stringToJson["path"]` or `stringToJson.path` to get directly the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

> How could I do that programmatically without having to write the path element by element ?

unfortunately there is not much more you can do with the bare operators and syntax of JavaScript without adding something like a custom function. You can do

```
> guysArray[i].guy1.name
"Joe"
```

but it's not gonna help you too much right now if you want something *more general*.

> Am I obligated to create a loop structure or there is a better saving structure for pathToName?

A function would work fine, but you may find interesting the idea that the sequence of keys in a JSON could be the *path* to the value.

In your case the name is at the path `"guy1.name"` so you could do a function that takes in this *path*, splits it every `"."` and then walks the JSON using the elements of the *path* as the keys.

```
> fromPath(guysArray[i], "guy1.name")
"Joe"
```

This idea is described as JSONpath and should be doable for you to implement as your own function.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted to know :)

Comment: Effectively I was looking a way to be more generic in my approach.